# Capacitor with React and API Dotnet, problem with API and android

Tags: reactjs, .net, firebase, api, capacitor

I use Capacitor with react and also sync with android. I use an API .NET connect to firebase. With my webapp react/capacitor, I can loggin. But on my emulator on Android studio, I can't. And don't error appeared.
So I will know if one of you have an idea ?

That is my capacitor.config.js

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'fr.wetseeds.mobile',
  appName: 'wetseeds-app-react',
  webDir: 'build',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https'
  }
};

export default config;
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I search many information on the net, but I just see configuration directly with Firebase in but as I use an API in .NET, I don't think it's the soluce.